# Security concerns for long-lasting single use access tokens with secondary identity verification?

Tags: passwords, token, one-time-password

I have an application that has a user type that "returns as needed" over the course of 22 days to complete action items. The application handles sensitive/confidential information, but > 90% of users do not use the system after 60 days. Less than 1% after a year.

I am trying to identify an opportunity to make completing on-demand action items as quick and easy as possible. To make signing in easier, when new action items are created we want to include a link with a token in the e-mail that expires when:

- A week has passed
- The user has successfully signed in

After clicking the link, the user is redirected to a page where verification information is requested (not a password). They must supply **one of the following**:

- Last 4 of SSN
- Zip and DOB

If they fail three attempts, their account is locked and can only be accessed by using the password supplied at sign-up or by completing a password reset. If the user attempts to access the app with an expired token, or by visiting the website directly instead of from an e-mail, both username and password are required.

Users have the ability to enable SMS 2FA after account creation at any time.

**My main concerns are:**

1. Is a week too long of a duration for this token? Even with secondary verification required.
2. Is locking an account after 3 token attempts too lenient?
3. Are there more user friendly standards that could speed up sign-in without compromising security?

Comment: #1 and #2 are quite subjective and depend on your perceived threat level, organizational efficiency and user convenience.  Your lockouts could be for an increasingly longer time (e.g. one hour at first, one day on three more failed attempts etc.) ([guidelines](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Blocking_Brute_Force_Attacks#Locking_Accounts)). For the first token, you could study the 90th percentile (as an example) and adjust accordingly.

Comment: You say locked out, but do you mean that? It sounds like what happens is that after three confirmation attempts of DOB/SSN, the link becomes invalidated and they must login with a uname/pword. That really isn't locked out

Comment: @NeilSmithline, that is a good point. I'll update my phrasing -- or, it's worth enforcing an actual lockout as it's unlikely the real user would not know that information (given its simplicity).

Comment: @DanielBrown I'm not a big lockout fan. They annoy users, cause support calls, and can be used in a denial if service attack. I think falling back to username,  password is appropriate